# Jasmine mocked promise method doesn't trigger then block

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-mock

I'm having trouble getting a mocked method that returns a promise to trigger the then connected to it.

Here is the service being tested. The get method is the important aspect of it.

```
angular.module('service.overtimeRules').factory('OvertimeRules', OvertimeRules);

function OvertimeRules(_, Message, OvertimeRulesModel) {
    const rules = [];

    return { get };

    function get() {
        return OvertimeRulesModel.get().then(
            data => {
                console.log('This never fires :(');
                rules.push(...data);
            },
            () => Message.add('Error retrieving the overtime rules.', 'danger')
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the spec file. The error I get is `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'OvertimeRulesModel.get')`. If I remove the get describe wrapper, the error goes away, but the service method's `then` block still doesn't fire.

```
describe('OvertimeRules', () => {
    let $q, $rootScope, deferred, Message, OvertimeRules, OvertimeRulesModel;

    beforeEach(() => {
        module('globals');
        module('service.overtimeRules');
        module($provide => {
            $provide.value('Message', Message);
            $provide.value('OvertimeRulesModel', OvertimeRulesModel);
        });

        inject((_$q_, _$rootScope_, _OvertimeRules_) => {
            $q = _$q_;
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            OvertimeRules = _OvertimeRules_;

            deferred = { OvertimeRulesModel: { get: $q.defer(), update: $q.defer } };

            Message = jasmine.createSpyObj('Message', ['add']);

            OvertimeRulesModel = jasmine.createSpyObj('OvertimeRulesModel', ['get']);
            OvertimeRulesModel.get.and.returnValue(deferred.OvertimeRulesModel.get.promise);
        });
    });

    describe('get', () => { // why would this cause an error?
        it('gets a list of rules and pushes them into the rules array', () => {
            deferred.OvertimeRulesModel.get.resolve(['rules']);
            OvertimeRules.get();
            $rootScope.$digest(); // $apply doesn't work either
            expect(OvertimeRules.rules).toEqual(['rules']);
        });
    });
});
```

Possibly important notes:

- I'm happy to approach this another way as long as the code is concise and readable. Also, I need to reject promises as well.
- `OvertimeRulesModel` is another factory in this `service.overtimeRules` module; `Message` is part of a separate module.
- I tried moving `OvertimeRulesModel` to its own module, but got the same error.
- I'm using the
  `A = jasmine.createSpyObj(...); A.get.and.returnValue(promise);`
  approach in a controller spec and everything is working fine
- These are unit tests, so I'd prefer to avoid injecting the actual `OvertimeRulesModel` service.

Answer (score 0):

### Better answer

Seems like I was losing reference the variables being supplied to the module provider. Solution is just to move the `createSpyObj` calls above the `$provide` statement.

```
...
module('service.overtimeRules');

Message = jasmine.createSpyObj('Message', ['add']);
OvertimeRulesModel = jasmine.createSpyObj('OvertimeRulesModel', ['get']);

module($provide => {
    $provide.value('Message', Message);
    $provide.value('OvertimeRulesModel', OvertimeRulesModel);
});
...
```

Going with solution fixed another issue I ran into. Also, I didn't have to change the `returnValue` syntax.

### Old answer:

And apparently, all I needed to do was change `returnValue` to `callFake` like so:

```
OvertimeRulesModel = jasmine.createSpyObj('OvertimeRulesModel', ['get']);
OvertimeRulesModel.get.and.callFake(() => deferred.OvertimeRulesModel.get.promise);
```